# Joomla Community Builder change field to jos_users from jos_comprofiler

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to add a field to a user's profile using Joomla's Community Builder extension. When I add the field, it automatically puts it in the jos_comprofiler table, but I want the field to be in the jos_users table. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this as Community Builder is an extender for things such as user, therefore uses it's own tables for additional fields. If you change the table, you will have to change all php file referring to jos_comprofiler

Comment: note will be #__comprofiler instead of jos_comprofiler in the php file!

Comment: I wanted to do it so that I wouldn't have to join 2 tables in a mysql query in a php script